# Is there a way to detect state of multiple angular components?

Tags: angular, detection, tic-tac-toe

I followed a tutorial to make a Tic-Tac-Toe app and am now trying to add further functionality on my own.

The draw condition is the main hurdle I am stuck at. Each tile in the tic tac toe grid is it's own Angular Component that has been created using *ngFor directive. Here's that code.

```
<app-square 
        *ngFor="let val of squares; let i = index" 
        [value]="val"
        (click)="makeMove(i)"> 

    </app-square>
```

Upon clicking, the button checks for a pre existing value and then if absent, applies a value (X or O) based on whose turn it is.

I have tried using click count based methods but none have panned out. Also, the winning condition is designed so that if a variable "winner" is no longer null, it would announce whatever is in winner variable. Here's the code for that.

```
<h2 *ngIf="winner">
    Player {{ winner }} won the game!
</h2>
```

Is there any way I can design a flag for each button that can be used to detect if all of them have values in them, thereby implying that the game has resulted in a draw?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already have everything in place. Just, in the parent component, add an additional check for an array of `squares`. If it is filled with Ok values, set winner to true.

It might look like this

```
this.winner = this.squares.every(x=>x===true)
```

Instead of true, use the value you are using.